# Debugging with Jetty Maven Plugin in Eclipse on multi module project: Compilation unit not on the build path

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, jetty, multi-module

I want to run a multi-module project in Eclipse with the Jetty Maven Plugin. [The project](https://svn.52north.org/svn/swe/main/SOS/Service/trunk/SOS/52n-sos/) runs just fine, and running `mvn jetty:run-exploded` the configuration files get processed correctly.

*Maven setup:*

```
/parent/pom.xml
/parent/module-1/pom.xml
/parent/module-2/pom.xml
/parent/module-service/pom.xml (this is the one that builds the webapp)
```

*Eclipse setup:*
The project and all modules are Maven projects in the workspace, the module projects are also Java projects.

I added the standard Jetty configuration to /module-service/pom.xml and also *run Maven on the module-service/pom.xml*.

However, when I want to **debug** I run into the following error when I want to use the content assist:

> This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project.

Also, hot code replacement does not work. But the variables and all breakpoints are detected correctly! What I do see is that that the editor that opens the file in the parent project (and as a side effect the editor has a different Java file icon, a hollow blue J instead of a full blue J).

Solutions tried so far:

- Adding the Java facet to the parent project > The source folders get detected correctly but I get just a lot of build path errors because the parent project does not have the pointers to all the libraries of the modules.
- Adding the modules to the build path of the module-service project.
- Checking *Resolve Workspace artifacts* in the Debug configuration (results in error "Failed to copy file for artifact"), possible solved [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAPPASM-82), but I don't see how.

I use jetty-maven-plugin version 8.1.4.v20120524.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe useful for somebody.

Try to use jetty:run goal and select "Resolve Workspace artifacts" in Run configurations/Maven Build/yourProject/Main|Tab| (where yourProject is the one you're running with jetty:run goal). Of course you have to have all dependent project imported usig "Import->Existing Maven Project".